# Ugly Line and Border Rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I just started diving into WPF. First thing I noticed and which I really hate is the ugly rendering.

I don't know why but for example borders or lines turning ugly sometimes.
Take a look at the Screenshot. The bottom line is ugly. Not that crisp like the centered line.

Any suggestions to make that better?

[image: Ugly Line Rendering]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the second answer of this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399731/when-should-i-use-snapstodevicepixels-in-wpf-4-0)
which suggests using UseLayoutRounding=False in preference to SnapsToDevicePixels.
As an aside if you're using bitmaps then RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode can be useful (from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592017/my-images-are-blurry-why-isnt-wpfs-snapstodevicepixels-working)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your lines don't fall on pixel boundaries.  Two ways I've used to get around this are:

Use [SnapsToDevicePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx).  This can cause some noticeably odd spacing if you have lines sufficiently close together.

or

Increase the width of your line so that it full hits a line of pixels. (this has the drawback that the needed width is, again, device dependent).